# SSH Tunnel - HTTPS hostname mismatch

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, ip, https, tunnel

I'm trying to view a https page on test12 server, from my MACHINE2, using a **SSH Tunnel** to connect to MACHINE1 which is on the same network as test12!
But i can not display it.

**test12** = *https server - 192.168.6.120 - same network as MACHINE1*

**MACHINE1** = *windows 7 x64 - 192.168.6.20 (the one running ssh server)*

**MACHINE2** = *windows 7 x64 - 192.168.2.8 (different network from MACHINE1)*

MACHINE2 connects to MACHINE1 and creates a tunnel to 192.168.6.120:443 on local port 443 and host 127.0.0.1.

(**127.0.0.1:443**)MACHINE2----><(**PUBLIC.IP:22**)MACHINE1><---->(**192.168.6.120:443**)test12

But when i navigate using iexplore from MACHINE2 to https://localhost i read "**THIS PAGE CAN'T BE DISPLAYED**"

So i edited C:\Windows\System32\driver\etc\hosts as follows:

**127.0.0.1 test12**

and now by going on https://test12 i see different error message
"**THIS PAGE CAN'T BE DISPLAYED - Turn on TLS 1.0,TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2.**"

So now dns name is test12 resolving to 127.0.0.1
Could it be still mismatch because ip is not 192.168.6.120?
Should i change MACHINE2 ip address to 192.168.6.120?

Can anyone tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: It's not mismatch it's TLS error.

Comment: For starters something on 10.0.0.0/8 or 10.0.0.0/24 CANNOT communicate with something on 192.168.6.0/24 or 192.168.2.0/24 without routing so test12 and MACHINE1 are not on the same network.  You would be better off using routing instead of tunnels for this anyways.

Comment: #Andrew Smith... 
Thanks for your answer, do you have any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: #Desultory...
Edited my question, **test12** local IP Address is actually **194.120.250.6** and COMPUTER1 can ping that address and connect via iexplore to https page on that ip address.


also route -p, shows no routes to 194.120.250.6 on COMPUTER1!
Can you help me to solve?

Comment: edited my question again! found out IP of *test12* was actually *192.168.6.120*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the problem!**

Using **putty** to create ssh connection between **COMPUTER2** and **COMPUTER1**, in putty tool window under *Connection-SSH-Tunnels* create a tunnel with *source port 2200* and *dynamic destination - auto*! resulting in **D2200**

[image: Check Screenshot]

After the connection is established, in **iexplore** settings, set socks proxy **localhost:2200**!
Once done since socks proxy can't resolve dns you have to edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts as follows: **192.168.6.120 test12** and then navigating to https://test12 will show the page!
Also suggest to install page certificate in trusted roots.